# ratio with groupby pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with 3 columns, product_id, user_city, purchase (0 or 1) to see if the customer purchased or not the item.
I want to calculate the percentage of purchase by city 
For example, if my dataframe looks like this:

```
product_id   user_city  purchase 
    1          NYC         0
    2          NYC         1
    3          LA          1
    4          LA          1
    5          LA          1
    6          LA          0
```

here I would get:

```
      perc_purchase
NYC    0.5
LA     0.75
```

I have used groupedby with size() but this only gives me a count of 0 and 1 by city, no percentage.
Please, help!!

Comment: `df.groupby('user_city')['purchase'].mean().to_frame('perc_purchase')`

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
df.groupby('user_city')['purchase'].mean().sort_values().to_frame('purchase')
```

This will give you

```
           purchase
user_city          
NYC            0.50
LA             0.75
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much.
do you know if there is a way to name this new column?

Comment: @ansev replied above to this!

Comment: @PandasKoala, yes, just updated my answer to reflect that :)

Comment: yes! just saw that as well :-) thanks a lot.
Last question, let's say I want to display as well a column with the count of 0s and a column with the count of 1s. do you know how to do that?